# Lebesgue Integral - Self Learning

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request, lebesgue-integral, book-recommendation

I finished some courses on Calculus at college sometime ago, then it goes without saying I learned Riemann Integrals. However, I realized that there is another type of integrating functions: Lebesgue Integrals. Because of this, I really would like to understand them by my own.

Which books would you recommend for me, who wants to learn by my on during this quarantine. It would be nice if the book contained exercises or even were like Stewart's Calculus.

Thank you

Comment: I would recommend some textbook introductory to real analysis that cover some of Lebesgue integration, by try the free electronic version of *Real analysis* of [this site](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/Free-Downloads.php). If you can't follow the book because it is so advanced then first complete the textbook *Elementary real analysis* from the same site. Also take a look at the book of Pugh to see if it fit well, it seems kinda elementary and have Lebesgue integration

Comment: Surely I give a try to them. Thanks for answering!

Comment: It seems you would like some understanding of the idea without going all the way into rigorous analysis. If that's the case I recommend a hands off exposition, Wikipedia's is well written.

Comment: I have read once. The problem was how $d\mi$ works. However, after this question, I will read more carefully, since I know more about than the first time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the question, but first I'd like to say that if you really are operating at the level of rigor of Stewart's calculus book (as opposed to more advanced calculus or analysis books that emphasize proofs), it seems unlikely to me that you'll find learning the details of Lebesgue integration feasible or useful.

With that reservation, I can recommend either of the following two concise introductions:
- Bartle, *The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure*.
- Burkill, *The Lebesgue Integral*.

Incidentally, Burkill is also the author of *A First Course in Mathematical Analysis* and *A Second Course in Mathematical Analysis*. The first of these would likely provide sufficient background for studying his book on the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: First off, welcome to the community! Secondly, thanks for your answer. So, I figured that out some time ago and I had kind of given up on learning Lebesgue Integrals. Meanwhile I had read some parts of some books on both Real and Complex Analysis: Elon's book on Real Analysis and Conways' on Complex. They were hard in the beginning but I got used to them. I'll surely try to get these recommended books. Hopefully, I'll understand more than the last time... By the way, it is incredible how theses books are different from Stewart's. Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about *Análisis real, Volumen 1*  by Elon Lages Lima? I'm not really familiar with that book, but I've just had a look at its table of contents. Based on that, it seems like a reasonable first step after Stewart. It looks similar to the first book by Burkill. You don't need to get too many books that cover the same material. I'd just focus on the two you're working on now, especially the one on real analysis.

Answer (score 2):

I reccomend you :

-[A Radical Approach to Lebesgue's Theory of Integration](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521711835)

-[The Integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron, and Henstock](https://www.amazon.es/Integrals-Lebesgue-Henstock-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0821838059)

The only prerequisite is elementary real analysis.

Comment: I try to get them. Thanks for your recommendation!